# kvm setup for linux without default modules

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, kvm, chroot, google-chrome-os

Ok, so the KVM setup guide in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535302/android-studio-kvm-setting) does not work for me,

this is because I am using crouton with a trusty (14.04) chroot.

Apparently somewhere along the line kvm modules were not shipped in ChromeOS or the crouton virtual images that I have knowledge of...

Since modules are not present, they are not modprobable.

How do I get, build, and deploy KVM, from such a starting point? To the point where I can successfully utilize Android Studio's built in emulator UI?

Comment: In a chroot env you need to get the package manager working then install the kernel headers etc for the Host machine version.

Comment: @Harry abstractly I know what you mean, I have a couple of working package managers. When you say host machine do you mean headers for ChromeOS? or do you mean headers in the trusty chroot?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve. If the Host kernel ie in your case I believe it's Chrome OS was not build to support KVM then you cannot build a module and insert it into that kernel, it won't work because the necessary plumbing won't exists in the kernel for it.

Answer (score 3):

why not to go clean, easy and simple ?

If you can install docker on your environement, go for a simple solution : use docker to launch prepackaged android studio this supports emulation and also connected devices (via usb).

A good dockerfile (image) can be found here: 
https://github.com/hasuf/docker-dev-android . This supports emulation & android connected devices

References:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/kelvinlawson/android-studio/
- http://reul.space/blog/running-android-studio-from-a-docker-dot-io-container/

Comment: Also if the prepackaged android studio requires kvm then I still have the same issue...

Comment: I don't think that you'll have the same issue docker is running in a virtual (separate environnement). Worth the cost to try. Using it over linux and windows myself with no problems at all. :)

Comment: Does this include emulator support?

Comment: Updated response. Yes supported !

Comment: Emilator is supported

Comment: this is a turnaround, but works like a charm. Havve you been testing it hellyale. Can you set my response as correct response for bounty please. If needing more support let me know, even by chat.

Comment: Will test today, didn't have time yesturday

Comment: `Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?`

No idea what this is... also it looks like this is going to be Android Studio 1.1 I need 2.1, or the newest Android Studio version

Comment: Got to go take an exam though, ill resume later

Comment: seems can't redirect, this post might help you now : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528337/am-i-trying-to-connect-to-a-tls-enabled-daemon-without-tls

Comment: docker appears to be just another rabbithole of errors. I'm already far enough down the kvm rabbithole, I have android studio installed already, so i dont need to dock it, what I need is kvm.